# javascript when you have to pass in an url as a parameter to mysql using jquery ajax and php how to do this and process return data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've got a piece of javascript as follows:

```
 $.ajax({
   type:"get",
   url:"http://www.orc23.com/get.php",
   data: { solution: src },
   datatype: "json",
   success: function(returndata){
    alert(returndata);
   }
});
```

And this is the corresponding php file that interacts with mysql:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("orc23com.fwdsfawmsdfaysql.com","ssft","dsfss123","cookies");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

mysqli_select_db($con, "cookies");

$sql="SELECT SOLUTION FROM requests WHERE theurl = '$_GET[solution]')";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);         
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$returndata=json_encode($row);
echo $returndata;

mysqli_close($con)
?>
```

The variable "src" I am passing in is a URL (string) , so I believe I should be treating it in a different way b/c of the nature of an URL with all its' special characters ,,,, I am running my code and it errors out as a "null" , but when I run the appropriate sql statement query in mysql DB then the DB returns what I am expecting ..... please advise what I may be doing wrong please ?

the sql I am running is this:

SELECT solution
FROM  `requests` 
WHERE theurl = 'https://www.google.com/fskdfalkadsl?=sksdkalsk&soccer=uwiw'
;

I know it will return back to me single row with just one column , and know what to expect as the value , but I can't seem to get the "get.php" page to return anything but "null" it seems ....

Answer (score 0):

You get `NULL` because PHP does not automatically populate the `$_GET` when it receives JSON formatted data, so there is nothing in  `$_GET['solution']`. You need to capture and decode the input yourself.

Instead of:

```
$solution = $_GET['solution'];
```

You need

```
$data     = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$solution = $data['solution'];
```

Or something close to it.